# My array elements change value after I increment my counter

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to read in a file to a character array, but whenever I increment my counter (for the array elements), my array elements seem to change value.
In the following code, I'm printing out the array values before the counter is incremented and after the counter is incremented (to find out the problem).

I'm not sure how to fix this (the code is in C)...

```
char fileContents[rowNum * colNum];
rewind(file);

int count = 0;
while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
   if(ch != '\n'){
      fileContents[count] = ch;
      printf("%c ", fileContents[count]);
      count++;
      printf("%c %d\n", fileContents[count - 1], count - 1);
  }
}
```

These are the file contents"

```
XXXX XXXX
XX XXX XX
X X X X X
XX XX XXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: After incrementing the counter, you print `fileContents[count]` instead of `fileContents[count-1]`.

Comment: Have you tried 1) using a file in which all of the characters are *different,* 2) doing this without file I/O, 3) using two `printf` statements that are identical except for the index, or 4) dispensing with the loop? Would you consider telling us what results you get? Would you condescend to give us a complete example of the code, so that we can copy, paste, compile and run without having to fill in the missing parts?

Comment: I actually found out what happened, my code for finding row/column dimensions was incorrect so my array wasn't allocating properly. Thanks though!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try

```
char fileContents[rowNum * colNum];
rewind(file);

int count = 0;
while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
   if(ch != '\n'){
      fileContents[count] = ch;
      printf("%c ", fileContents[count]);
      printf("%c %d\n", fileContents[count - 1], count);
      count++;
  }
}
```

I added the `count++` statement after the printf because there is the possibility that you increase `count` and `count = fileContents.size()`; this implies `fileContents[count]` is out of bounds

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why, instead of just giving a "code-only" answer

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I've changed my answer.

Comment: Well the problem is that when I try to see what's in my array after I come out of the "while" loop, the array is filled with "? T h H u" instead of "X X  X    X  X". It works fine inside the loop all the way until I increment...

Comment: Why are you moving the `count++` around, and why aren't you using `count-1` twice in the line that uses it once?

Comment: I was trying to see why my array was getting corrupted. When I print before I increment, the output is correct (compared to the file). When I print after I increment, the output is incorrect. I changed my code to print out printf("%c %d\n", fileContents[count - 1], count - 1);

This works all the way till the 39th element, and then gets corrupted again.

Edit: changed a number

Comment: Providing the file contents would help

Comment: @asuma that comment doesn't make sense; your increment is inside your loop

Comment: would `rowNum * colNum` happen to be 38? (or smaller)

Comment: Looks like my rowNum and colNum were incorrect and so my array wasn't allocated properly... Not sure why I didn't get a compiler error for that though.

Comment: @asuna: That's a runtime error, not a compile-time error.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for answering my question! This is my first time posting a question, so am I supposed to "star" an answer or something?

Comment: Also note that that array is only going to be validly allocated within that enclosing block.  If that's a function or something and you return from it, expect the contents of that array to get trashed (and peeking at them then is undefined behavior regardless).

Comment: @asuna If you feel this answer has helped you, you may upvote the answer by clicking the up-arrow (once you have 15 reputation). Otherwise, you may check this as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark (after 10 minutes have passed since you posted the question).

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation yet, but I will checkmark.

Edit: Looks like "possible" was now.